# CPU utilization constant 99% for SQL SERVER on vmware virtual machine

Tags: performance, vmware, cpu-usage, sql-server-performance

I configure sql server 2014 on a VMware virtual machine .
The issues is that all the time cpu utilization is 99% and that effect the web application and it become super slow to load the page.
I increase the cores in VMware for this virtual machine but still cpu utilization varies within 90 to 99 % and application is still slow.

- OS : Windows Server 2012 R2
- Database : Sql Server 2014
- Number Of virtual Sockets : 2
- Number Of Cores per socket : 6

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

which OS you install the sql server?

What you see in the task manager?`

Check the DISK IO on the VM as DB and vCenter are on the same box, Move the disks to high end storage

Can you install the sysinternal tools to get more infos?

R\Sven

Comment: OS : Windows Server 2012 R2 Database : Sql Server 2014 , in task manager I can see Sql Server is utilizing 99% of cpu